How to fix gradual FPS drops and excessive GC allocations with coroutines?
I made a game. The FPS is fine at the beginning. As time goes by, the FPS drops. I saw from the Profiler that the reason for this is GC Alloc.
I was told that coroutines should be used to write optimized code, but when you call a coroutine in a loop, GC Alloc increases according to the number of calls. I thought WaitUntil worked when the conditions were true, but I think the bloating in the loop is due to the WaitUntil I wrote in the first line of the coroutine.
What can I do to prevent this?

There are more optimization techniques than we could hope to write down in an answer here, so we can't give you a universal recipe to optimize everything. What we can do is help you optimize a specific example. Try editing your question to include the code you're using with these coroutines, and we can help you find more efficient ways to achieve similar behaviours.

And this sounds more like you have a memory leak. Not optimized code should give you from the beginning a low fps IF the code is your bottle neck.

Thank you for profiling - that's a great first step! Next, I would try to use the profiler (and related tools) to figure out what's triggering the GC alloc - check the profiling docs for for info on deep profiling & also how "to find out which call stacks lead to a GC.Alloc sample."

GC will not cause a gradual slowdown as the workload for GC is constant compared to allocations. GC slowdown is a symptom not a cause.

Thank you very much for your answer. I have a question in mind. My game is an RPG game. One of my skills is to make a meteor fall from the sky. I get this meteor from resources. When I use this skill, I don't see much slowdown. If I don't use it and declare it as public and leave it in the inspector, will I have a problem? There are some fruit trees in my game, will I have this problem even if I don't spawn this fruit tree, or will I have this problem when I summon it?

@DMGregory I'll add a code sample when I open the game project. Thanks for your answer.

@Blindman67 I understand what you mean. Thanks for your answer.

Profiling it first is a great start!
The most likely way memory allocation could be slowing things down is that you run out of RAM. If you have used up all the space available on your actual RAM, Windows will start to use a "page file". This means it's using part of your hard disk as memory. The hard disk is considerably slower than your RAM.
Imagine as example a "bullet hell" game. Throughout the game, a lot of bullets are created, and then destroyed again if they hit something or go off-screen. Now, if something in C# still has a reference to each of these bullets - or even just a part of it - the GC will not be able to deallocate their memory. Even though a single bullet might be small in terms of memory, at some point it will not fit on your RAM anymore.
So for such a game, we need to make sure to not keep any reference to these bullets after they are destroyed, so the GC can free up their memory again. Alternatively - especially if (de-)allocation itself becomes a bottle neck - the Object Pool Pattern can be used (in short, you keep them in memory and reuse them).
You need more info
Thanks to profiling we know a lot more, but only knowing the "area" of the problem (allocation) is not quite enough to solve it. There is a way to see where exactly it is coming from (quoted from the Unity Forums):

If you want to see where the allocations actually come from you’ll need to enable Deep Profiling which can be done as follows:
Editor: If you’re profiling the editor you can select ‘Deep Profile’ and it will recompile and work magically when you next play.

At the risk of overstating the obvious: Don't take the first result you find with this. Memory allocation in itself is not a bad thing, and even necessary. So make sure that the specific allocation you're looking at with this deep profiling is not for e.g. a ship upgrade which spawns 5 times per level, while the real issue is the with the 2 million bullets spawned in other places.
Coroutines
Coroutines don't make things faster. Actually, technically they even make things a tiny bit slower because they have a little bit of overhead. Their purpose is only to provide an easy way to spread work over multiple frames.
Simplified example: You need to read 50 files from the hard disk. Together, this takes half a second. This causes a clearly visible framerate stutter, after which the loading bar you put on the screen jumps from 10% to 60%.
A coroutine is an easily readable way to allow you to load a file, update the loading bar, wait a frame, load a file, update the loading bar, wait a frame, etc... until all are loaded.
⚠️If after reading this you realize you have overused coroutines to an extreme degree, I'd actually suggest you rectify that situation first!
Coroutines were known to have some issues with GC (in the past at least), so getting rid of them where they are unnecessary and only add complexity - which is advisable anyway - might already solve your problem.
